# Format a number value with minimal decimal points

Tags: c#, .net

I need to format a number (decimal) into a string with minimal decimal points.
for example, let's say the minimal decimal point is 3

- 123.123654 => 123.123654
- 123.12 => 123.120
- 123.1 => 123.100
- 123 => 123.000

What is the best way to achieve this result?

Comment: What is the *type* of the `number`? Is it `decimal` or `double`? If it's `decimal` just add `0.000m`: `string result = (number + 0.000m).ToString();`

Comment: Floating point numbers cannot be stored exactly. So it is almost impossible to know how many decimal digits are significant. Related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/112968)

Comment: the number is a decimal

Comment: For `decimal` you can do `num % 0.001M == 0` to determine if it has more or less than 3 significant digits and then format accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you use really a `decimal` the decimal places are preserved, so you can write:

```
decimal d = 123.120m;
Console.WriteLine(d);  // 123.120
```

If you can't do this you can always provide a format with `ToString`:

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N3"));
```

Reading: [Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), especially. [numeric format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString)

As juharr pointed out this shows just 3 decimal places. You can use `string.Format`:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:0.000##################}", d);
```

Comment: The N3 format limits the number of digits after the decimal but the OP wants all of them if there are more than 3.

Comment: @juharr: good point. Edited: using string.Format is the best i came up with.